# How to run rspec tests in parallel for non-rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, rspec

I'm trying find out how to make rspec tests multithreaded.

```
describe 'Suite' do
  it 'first' do
    ...
  end

  it 'second', type: :thread do
    ...
  end

  it 'third', type: :thread do
    ...
  end
end
```

In this case I want running tests in parallel which specified type as thread, non-specified type tests should be run in single thread. How Can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you want to run all tests in parallel to speed up the whole test suite? Did you consider using the [parallels_tests](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests) gem?

Comment: Because tests sometimes will use same resources  and run them in parallel can be conflicting. And this tests are integration and have heavy before all preconditions and I can't split tests to separated files. Yep, I've seen this gem but not sure if it has functionallity what I need.

Comment: When running your test in parallel leads to conflicts for resources, then you should fix that problem first, because you have to expect the same situation a webserver anyway: Two users click the same link at the same time, a user double clicks a button. Concurrency is the default on webservers.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try gems like [parallel_tests](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests) and [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) ?

BTW, you can mark some slow tests with tag @slow and run it with different commands: `rake rspec:slow_tests` and `rake rspec:other_tests` in different terminal tabs intime, etc.